# ActionBar DropDown padding causes blank space [landscape mode]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

Currently I have the following style.xml

**UPDATED - All relevant styles included**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome</item>
</style>
<style name="MyDropDownStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">240dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">240dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

This allows me to set move the DropDown 240dp away from its X axis which works quite good. See Screenshot #1

**Screenshot #1**
[image]

But as a side effect this padding causes a blank "space" on the right side of the popup itself. See screenshot #2

**Screenshot #2**
[image]

How can I set a fixed size of the Popup or ignore the padding being set by DropDown style?

**UPDATED**

The reason for the paddingLeft is to not overlap with logo (defined as background)

```
<item name="background">@drawable/logo</item>
```

**UPDATE 2 - Screenshot without dropDownHorizontalOffset style**

[image]

PS:

`dropDownHorizontalOffset`  is only used to set the X axis of the Popup matching to match the paddingLeft

Comment: Although I do not understand why you would want such paddings, the menu popup should not be like this. Post some more code relative to it so we can help (styles etc). What if you remove `android:dropDownHorizontalOffset`?

Comment: Well, I already noticed that android development is -ne barrier-free development. Im pretty sure I only need to know how to set the popup style (like width) to solve the problem - Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea how you ended up with a popup menu on the left... Using AppCompat? Toolbar? Any base theme?

Comment: This popup is a default behavior of the AppCompat theme when there is less space for the tabs Imo - I havent added any additional layouts

Comment: Isn't drop down selector / tabs deprecated with AppCompat? I believe it is. I know no workaround for it, sorry.

Comment: Well, I think it is but its often easier to keep old things than working on new stuff - I am going to change it now to use toolbar which should allow me to add a "spinner" with custom width, etc.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround is to replace the ActionBar with the new toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) and add a Spinner (DropDown) right inside of it

*Code lines have been changed for better illustration and are not tested*

**main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/navigationBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:background="@drawable/logo"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <Spinner
                android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);

    setupSpinnerTabs();

    // for device orientation purpose
    displaySpinner(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
}

private void setupSpinnerTabs() {
    ToolbarSpinnerAdapter adapter = new ToolbarSpinnerAdapter(toolbar.getContext());

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    // the below is used for the selection "change event" of the spinner
    //spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerSelection());
}
```

**ToolbarSpinnerAdapter.java**

```
public class ToolbarSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
    Context context;

    ToolbarSpinnerAdapter(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return "Spinner here"
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View defaultView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_spinner_dropdown_layout, null);
        // [...]

        text.setText( this.getItem(position).toString() );
        return defaultView;
    }
}
```

The result should look quite simliar to the below image:

[image]

PS: In Portrait orientation there might not be enough space for the Spinner